# Accessing Same object in different C function in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have to write the methods as C Function so as to access the object every time, I want to declare that object inside the function and allocate it. How can I maintain a common object in all C Functions. Is it Possible?

```
void method1
{
    NSMutableArray *sample = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

void method2
{
    NSMutableArray *sample = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Comment: make it a global variable? or a class variable?

Comment: @FaddishWorm make it Global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 static NSMutableArray *sampleArray=nil;
 @implementation class
 void method1(void){
    if (sampleArray ==  nil){
       sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     }
  }                     
  void method2(void){
    if (sampleArray ==  nil){
       sampleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     }
}
```

kindly use this

Answer (score 2):

I believe this should work (although this is *definitely* not thread-safe):

```
NSMutableArray *sample = nil;

void method1 {
    if (sample == nil) {
        setupSample();
    }
    // ...
}

void method2 {
    if (sample == nil) {
        setupSample();
    }
    // ...
}

void setupSample {
    sample = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Any other setup here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use class methods to access a shared object.

something like...

```
void method {
NSMutableArray *mySharedObj = [SampleRelatedContextClass sample];
}
```

This just looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Create static file-scoped variable.

```
static NSMutableArray *sample=nil;

@implementation class

void method1(){ //you can write c functions outside  @implementation also
if (sample==nil) {
        sample = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }   

}

void method2(){
if (sample==nil) {
    sample = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
}
@end
```

**NOTE:** You can not use objective-c instance variable in c functions

Comment: Technically, that's not a global variable, it's a static *file-scoped* variable. It just means it cannot be `extern`'d into other source files, basically.